# Como uso correctamente las consultas para que me lo consulte las veces que yo quiera?

Tags: c#, mysql, mysqlconnector

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en `c#` y `mysql`, ahora tengo un problema, tengo generando con arreglos objetos y esos mismos están en ciclo y en otro ciclo hice arreglos con variables y una consulta la cual lo que necesito no lo imprime en los labels generadas.

al momento de correr la aplicación solamente consulta el primero

```
    for (int cont3 = 0; cont3 < cont; cont3 = cont3 + 1)
    {
        string query3 = "SELECT isusuario, imagen, telefono, correo, descripcion, fecha FROM post;";
        MySqlConnection databaseConnection3 = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        MySqlCommand commandDatabase3 = new MySqlCommand(query3, databaseConnection3);
        databaseConnection3.Open();
        MySqlDataReader leer3 = commandDatabase3.ExecuteReader();
        while (cont)
        {
            idusuario[cont3] = Convert.ToInt32(leer3.GetValue(0));

            aImag[cont3] = aImagen((byte[])leer3["imagen"]);
            pcPubli[cont3].Image = new Bitmap(aImag[cont3], pcPubli[cont3].Size);
            Pnblanco[cont3].Controls.Add(pcPubli[cont3]);

            cel[cont3] = Convert.ToInt32(leer3.GetValue(2));
            correo[cont3] = leer3.GetValue(3).ToString();

            //fecha = leer3.GetValue(5).ToString();
            //LblFecha.Text = fecha;

            descrip[cont3] = leer3.GetValue(4).ToString();
            LblPubli[cont3].Text = descrip[cont3];       
        }
        databaseConnection3.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Para esos casos deberias optar por usar un gridview dime las razones por la cual no lo usas.